# Django CBV - How to avoid repeating the get_context_data for every view just to get a custom title?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm setting a `{{ title }}` for every page of my project. Sometimes this `title` is a static string such as `Enter your Name` and sometimes it's based on a relevant object on that page, such as `Employee.first_name`.

To create `context['title']`, I'm using `get_context_data` inside every class based view. But this seems to be resulting in me repeating a chunk of code every time, and I'm looking to reduce that somehow.

For example to write a custom title for each page, I'd have to write this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(SomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['title'] = 'Title for This page'
    return context
```

I feel like it'd be ideal to have a mixin that I somehow just pass in the variable for `title` and my `context` dictionary will automatically have `context['title']` added based on the passed in variable.

Is this possible? Is there a way to create a mixin such that all I have to do is pass in a variable, and it'll give me a context *just* for the title instead of writing out that chunk of code for every single view?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible and easy:

```
class YourTitleMixin(object):
    title = None # or your default title if you won't provide any

    def get_title(self):
        return self.title

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context= super(YourTitleMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = self.get_title()
        return context
```

And you use it:

```
def YourPageView(YourTitleMixin, DetailView):
    title = "Your Page Title" # you can either use this ...

    def get_title(self):
        return self.get_object().name # ... or that, if your title should be generated from some data
```

But is this necessary? Are you using your title only once in template? Do you share one template between views? Maybe you can do it purely in your templates? For example:

```
{# base.html #}
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{% block page_title %}My page{% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
</html>
```

---

```
{# detail.html #}
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}{{ article.name }} - {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}
{# will result in "article name - My Page". You don't need to use super if you don't want to #}
```

Comment: that's also what I was thinking, but I like setting the title in the view because I often share a template with multiple views.

Comment: Be careful with `get_object`, it will add one query to your view since it is already called in `super().get_context_data() `;)

Comment: You can also use super in mixin-based solution to get title from parent class and glue 2 titles together, like in example of template-based solution. Also you can mix both solutions to get even more flexibility. It's totally up to you.

Answer (score 2):

I usually solve this with a mixin:

```
class TitleMixin(object):
    """Pass a defined title to context"""

    title = None

    def get_title(self):
        return self.title

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = self.get_title()

        return context
```

In you views, you can then do:

```
class BlogIndex(TitleMixin, ListView):
    title = 'Blog entries'

class EntryDetail(TitleMixin, DetailView)
    def get_title(self): # for dynamic title, such as coming from a model field
        return self.object.title
```

Comment: This won't work.  You probably meant `context['title'] = self.get_title()`?

Comment: does this assume every model has a `get_title` method define in their model definition? What if I wanted the title "All blog entries from author: `author.first_name`" ? That kind of title is a mix of static data and object data.

Comment: You can return in get_title: `return "All blog entries from author: %s" % (self.author.first_name, )`

Comment: Yes, by overriding the `get_title` method you can combine static data and data coming from `self.object`, `self.queryset` or any other attribute on your view.